# LWJGL BufferedImage White Picture

Tags: java, textures, lwjgl, bufferedimage

I have a problem with loading an image and rendering it with LWJGL.

Here is the code for loading:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);

int[] pixels = new int[image.getWidth() * image.getHeight()];
image.getRGB(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), pixels, 0, image.getWidth());
ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(image.getWidth() * image.getHeight() * 3);

for(int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++){
    for(int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++){
        int pixel = pixels[y * image.getWidth() + x];
        buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF));     // Red component
        buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF));      // Green component
        buffer.put((byte) (pixel & 0xFF));             // Blue component

        byte red = (byte)((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF);
        byte green = (byte)((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF);
        byte blue = (byte)(pixel >> 8 & 0xFF);

        System.out.println("Pixel " + x + "x" + y + " = R:" + red + " G:" + green + " B:" + blue);
    }
}

buffer.flip();

textureID = GL11.glGenTextures();
GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGB, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 0, GL11.GL_RGB, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
```

The RGB output looks correct, but when I render the image I see only a white area.

The code for rendering:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, image.getTextureID());
glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
glVertex2i(0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(image.getWidth(), 0);
glVertex2i(0 + image.getWidth(), 0);
glTexCoord2f(image.getWidth(),  image.getHeight());
glVertex2i(0 + image.getWidth(), 0 + image.getHeight());
glTexCoord2f(0, image.getHeight());
glVertex2i(0, 0 + image.getHeight());
glEnd();
```

And this is how I initialize OpenGL:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, 0, -1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Texture coordinates are normalized to [0, 1]. That means that (0, 0) is in the bottom left corner of the texture and that (1, 1) is in the top right corner of the texture.

So, your vertices should look like this:

```
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2i(0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glVertex2i(0 + image.getWidth(), 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1,  1);
    glVertex2i(0 + image.getWidth(), 0 + image.getHeight());
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex2i(0, 0 + image.getHeight());
```